# Combinatorics - How many ways to create...

Tags: combinatorics

On how many ways can we build a set with $N$ positions containing 3 letters that third letter is before 2 first.

We have 3 letters $"AAB"$ and $N$ fields, possible answer for $4$ positions is:

BAA_

BA_A

B_AA

_BAA

than it is 4, how to calculate this?

Comment: for each permutation you have $ C_{N}^{3}$ ways. Here you have one permutation, and $C_{4}^{3} = 4 $ ways

Comment: @mounirbensalem What is symbol $C$ ?

Comment: @A.Nony The binomial coefficient, of course!

Comment: Okey, now everything is understandable for me. Thanks